# slide div with text-align center not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position

I've an edit div where a user can change his name. I made up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amNsN/12/) to show you my working version. I don't know why it's not working in JSFiddle, but on my site when I click the `profilEditButton` or the `profilSaveButton` the two divs slide the way they should do. My problem comes along with the layout of the profilDetails, and the input fields. As long as the name is long enough it looks quite okay but a short name breaks the layout and it looks terrible! Second point is that the mobile version looks bad anyway. So how can I align the text and the input fields in their divs that they are centered, even when the animation has done it's job?

Comment: Huh...? http://postimg.org/image/5nanm0gnj/ has no `profilEditButton` or `profilSaveButton`... Love to help, but you have to clarify further man... The code in the fiddle doesn't even have jQuery loaded, and I really have no idea what you would like us to do here.

Comment: I think you forgot to add jquery in the fiddle

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Cause I tested a few and I can't make it work as is.

Comment: I think it's a lot easier if you visit the site see my edit! @NicholasHazel I'm using 1.10.2

Comment: Am I missing something here...? [Fiddle with jQuery loaded](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/amNsN/10/) does nothing...

Comment: Is postimg.org/image/5nanm0gnj your site...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On #profilData, change left to 0 and add right set to 0. (`left: 0; right: 0;`)

What that does it makes the width of the `text-align: center` the width of the parent. It works because the parent has `position: relative` so basically you're telling the element, sit all the way on the left, and sit all the way on the right, which makes it the full width.

I tested this with a short, small, medium, and long name. All worked.